# A funny way of expressing the identity operator

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have encountered the following trick that people in C*-algebra use; but frankly I don't understand why really this is true.

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra acting non-degeneratly on a Hilbert space $H$ via its universal representation. Take a positive element $h\in A$, $\|h\|\leqslant 1$. How can one prove that the identity operator $I_H$ on $H$ can be written as

$$I_H=\mbox{SOT}\!-\!\lim_{n\to \infty} (h+\tfrac{1}{n}I_H)^{-1} h?$$

Comment: $I_H = \mbox{SOT}\!-\!\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (h+\tfrac{1}{n}I_H)^{-1} h$ means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (h+\frac{1}{n}I_H)^{-1} hx = x$ for all $x\in H$?

Comment: @Daniel It should be that...

Comment: If you use the spectral theorem to represent $h$ as a multiplication operator, this looks rather clear.

Comment: Etienne, ah that was easy. You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Maybe I should have done that: this would have made me realize that I was wrong (as Martin nicely showed below)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not the identity of $H$ what you get, but the range projection of $h$. For example if 
$$
h=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
(h+1/n I)^{-1}h=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{1/2+1/n}&0\\0&n\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}1/2&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1/2}{1/2+1/n}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
To show that this is always the case, take $h$ positive. Then, for $\xi=h\eta$,
$$
(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}h\,\xi-\xi=(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}\left[h\,\xi-(h+\frac1n\,I)\xi\right]=(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}\left[-\frac1n\,\xi\right]\\
=-\frac1n\,(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}\,h\eta.
$$
As $\|(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}h\|\leq1$ (just because $|t/(t+1/n)|\leq1$ for $t\geq0$), we have
$$
\|(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}h\,\xi-\xi\|=\frac1n\,\|(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}\,h\eta\|\leq\frac{\|\eta\|}n\to0,
$$
and the result extends to the closure of the range of $h$.

Finally, for $\xi\in(\text{ran}\,h)^\perp$, $h\xi=0$, so $(h+\frac1n\,I)^{-1}h\xi=0$.